# Update Images after edit via php

Tags: php, images, post-meta

After editing images directly inside the upload folder via PHP-functions, I managed to automatically regenerate the meta data, the thumbnails and the WebP copies. (Checked via FTP! Even the displayed meta data values are right)

But the displayed images (via HTTPS) in the frontend and in some parts of the backend are often still the old ones.

This does not happen if one uses the rotate / crop functions + "Save"-Button in the media library.

What are the related php-functions which force wordpress (and jetpack and caching plugins etc.) to update and use the new picture.

Please only answers about php code, not plugins!
Thanx, UHM

Comment: Are you referring to the resized versions thumbnail/medium/large/etc? Note that the Jetpack Photon CDN will require you to contact their support as 3rd party support is off topic here. As for caching plugins, there is no standardised/agreed upon cache flushing function/API

Comment: Refering to all versions: The problem is fixed once I rotate the images 90deg and back again -90deg and press "Save" .... So there must be a function behind the "save" button that updates anything, including Jetpack and the caching plugins ... I'm just not clever enough to find it out my self ...

Comment: likely because they're hooking into save filters that weren't triggered because you directly modified the files in the filesystem. The longterm fix is to not do that and use the WP APIs instead to do it

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Your question is pretty clear but it is often very helpful if you can provide concrete examples (the exact steps that lead to the error vs. the exact steps that produce correct results). For this question there are many, many possible places and reasons (server cache, plugin caching, browser caching) why you are seeing this behavior and a concrete example might help you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: The problem simplified and in other words: Jetpack CDN is not updated if I modify a jpg/png with my own php routines, but it is updated if it is done by the wordpress editor. What is the editor doing to achive this?